# NPOI color scale

Tags: c#, npoi

I am working with NPOI. How can I add color scale to a specific cell range excel's spreedsheet using c# and NPOI?

In MS Excel you can do this using Conditional Formatting -> Color scale.
[image: color scale]

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I highly doubt that the original poster is still searching for this answer six years on, I can offer up the following snippet which I have based off of this [Java POI example](https://thinktibits.blogspot.com/2014/09/Conditional-Formatting-Color-Scales-POI-Java-Example.html):

```cs
var conditionalFormatting = xssfSheet
    .GetCTWorksheet()
    .AddNewConditionalFormatting();

conditionalFormatting.sqref = "A1:B10";

var rule = conditionalFormatting.AddNewCfRule();
rule.type = ST_CfType.colorScale;
rule.priority = 1;

var colorScale = rule.AddNewColorScale();
var minValue = colorScale.AddNewCfvo();
minValue.type = ST_CfvoType.min;
minValue.val = "0";

var maxValue=colorScale.AddNewCfvo();
maxValue.type = ST_CfvoType.max;
maxValue.val = "0";

var lowColor = colorScale.AddNewColor();
var highColor = colorScale.AddNewColor();
lowColor.SetRgb(0xFC, 0xFC, 0xFF);
highColor.SetRgb(0xF8, 0x69, 0x6B);
```

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, here is a c# sample:

```cs
var scaleRule = sheet.SheetConditionalFormatting.CreateConditionalFormattingColorScaleRule();
var colorScaleFormatting = scaleRule.ColorScaleFormatting;

colorScaleFormatting.Thresholds[0].RangeType = RangeType.NUMBER;
colorScaleFormatting.Thresholds[0].Value = scale.Min;
colorScaleFormatting.Thresholds[1].RangeType = RangeType.NUMBER;
colorScaleFormatting.Thresholds[1].Value = scale.Mid;
colorScaleFormatting.Thresholds[2].RangeType = RangeType.NUMBER;
colorScaleFormatting.Thresholds[2].Value = scale.Max;

// NOTE we need to create a new array here, else the colors stay empty for some reason.
colorScaleFormatting.Colors = [
    new XSSFColor(IndexedColors.Red), 
    new XSSFColor(IndexedColors.Green), 
    new XSSFColor(IndexedColors.Red)
];
```

Then apply this to your sheet via `ISheet.SheetConditionalFormatting.AddConditionalFormatting(..., scaleRule)`