# XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting using Color Scale Rule is not formatting the data in excel generated using poi from java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to create color scale conditional formatting in excel generated through poi (4.0.1) in java using XSSFWorkbook functionalities. I don't see any changes in the data formatting although I tried many variations of sample codes available online to create a RED-YELLOW-GREEN color scale formatting. I am pasting the code which I am currently working on. Could someone help find what the issue is ?

```
        applyColorScale(cf, "J2:J21", "00FF0000", "0000FFFF", "0000FF00");
        applyColorScale(XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting cf, String region, String... colors) {
            XSSFConditionalFormattingRule cr = cf.createConditionalFormattingColorScaleRule();
            XSSFColorScaleFormatting color = cr.createColorScaleFormatting();
            int steps = 100 / (colors.length - 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
                XSSFConditionalFormattingThreshold th = color.createThreshold();
                if (i == 0) {
                    th.setRangeType(XSSFConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType.MIN);
                } else if (i == colors.length - 1) {
                    th.setRangeType(XSSFConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType.MAX);
                } else {
                    th.setRangeType(XSSFConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType.PERCENTILE);
                }
                th.setValue((double)steps*i);
                XSSFColor clr = color.createColor();
                clr.setARGBHex(colors[i]);
            }
            CellRangeAddress[] regions = {CellRangeAddress.valueOf(region)};
            cf.addConditionalFormatting(regions, cr);
        }
```

[image: Expected output in excel]

Comment: For readers using c#, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77954476/4122889

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [Conditional Formatting](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ConditionalFormatting) you find a link

> See more examples on Excel conditional formatting in
>   ConditionalFormats.java

Following this examples we get:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class ConditionalFormatting {

 public static void applyColorScale(SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF, String region, String... colors) {
  CellRangeAddress[] regions = { CellRangeAddress.valueOf(region) };
  ConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingColorScaleRule();
  ColorScaleFormatting csf = rule.getColorScaleFormatting();
  if (colors.length == 3) {
   csf.getThresholds()[0].setRangeType(ConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType.MIN);
   csf.getThresholds()[1].setRangeType(ConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType.PERCENTILE);
   csf.getThresholds()[1].setValue(50d);
   csf.getThresholds()[2].setRangeType(ConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType.MAX);
   for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
    ((ExtendedColor)csf.getColors()[c]).setARGBHex(colors[c]);
   }
  } else if (colors.length == 2) {
   csf.setNumControlPoints(2);
   csf.getThresholds()[0].setRangeType(ConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType.MIN);
   csf.getThresholds()[1].setRangeType(ConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType.MAX);
   for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
    ((ExtendedColor)csf.getColors()[c]).setARGBHex(colors[c]);
   }
  }

  sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, rule);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("new sheet");

  for (int r = 1; r < 20; r++) {
   sheet.createRow(r).createCell(9).setCellFormula("RANDBETWEEN(-100, 100)");
   sheet.getRow(r).createCell(11).setCellFormula("RANDBETWEEN(-100, 100)");
  }

  SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();

  applyColorScale(sheetCF, "J2:J21", "FFFF0000", "FFFFFF00", "FF00FF00");
  applyColorScale(sheetCF, "L2:L21", "FFFF0000", "FF00FF00");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("ConditionalFormatting.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Main differences to your code: Your created `XSSFColor`s are not used anywhere.  Only `RangeType.PERCENTILE` needs a value at all. The Alpha in `ARGB` should be `FF` instead of `00` to be fully opaque. Yellow is `FFFF00` not `00FFFF`